# Is it normal for a Hotel to kick out a sick child?

Tags: health, hotels, turkey

We were staying at a Hotel in Turkey and on day 5 our child became ill with HFMD ( hand, foot and mouth disease) the hotel Dr sent us to the hospital, on the same day 3 families with very young children were all admitted all from the same hotel. We had not flown in on the same flight, nor had any contact until we met at the hospital. The hotel kicked all of us out! 
Is this normal?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the hotel hasn't been forced to kick everyone out (i.e. close) by public health officials?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I would have thought so, but Google "hand foot mouth disease Turkey hotel" suggests that the disease is usually too minor to rise to that level. It also seems, from that search, to be common. I think it is more likely that they wished to merely to minimize spread, and I suspect it would have been better to arrange suitable more isolated accommodation rather than just chucking the families out.

Comment: No, they were not forced to throw anyone out, we got told whilst at the hospital still awaiting confirmation of our 2 year olds blood results by our travel company that the manager would not let us return. We were one of 3 families with under 3 year olds that day. They refused to let any of us return from the hospital except to collect our belongings. Our choice was to stay in the hospital? Although we had been discharged and told by the Dr that it was ok for us to take our boy back to the room or fly home.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the word "normal" is loaded in this context, but:

1. HFMD is transmissible via the air, so apart from forcing you all to wear masks (how?), sending you all away may have been prudent if the hotel wished to minimize exposure to other guests, and perhaps liability.
2. The fact that four different families all fell ill around the same time in the same place surely underscored the urgency of the situation.
3. In most parts of the world you are not guaranteed accommodation, for example if you show up with a gun a hotel might refuse you, regardless of whether your gun is legal.  Likewise if you show up with a fish in a tank, or [durian](http://runawayjuno.com/runaway-tales/why-no-durian-inside-rule-is-legitimate/)!
4. Different cultures treat illness differently.  I can't speak directly to Turkey (nor do I even know if the hotel proprietor was Turkish), but it's possible that they viewed your sick children as something like a bad omen.  If that were the case, as travellers we ought to accept it to the extent possible.

I hope that the hotel offered you a refund for any remaining days of your stay, and helped you find alternative accommodation.

Comment: My son got sick on day 5 of our stay, according to NHS guidelines incubation period is between 2 and 5 days! So it's highly likely that he caught it at the Hotel along with the other 2 children who had been there roughly the same time as us.

Comment: To clarify my child had HFMD, a common childhood illness. I was shocked that a Hotel would kick a sick child out. Normally a child from the UK or Germany where I live wouldn't even have to go to the hospital, even some nurseries don't stop the children with it. I could understand if it had been Ebola!